# Filter lines between matching strings

Tags: bash, grep, awk

Have a contents in file similar to below- There are many lines between START & END and might have errors/warnings too. I want to filter out errors/warning lines between START & END and skip if doesn't have.
Heading is varying with different names. But make logic of printing next line of START(should be heading)

```
START
Heading1
.......
errors
........
END

START
Heading2
........
........
........
END

START
Heading3
.......
errors
Warning...
END
```

Expected output below

```
Heading1
errors

Heading3
errors
Warning...
```

---

I have tried below , but this prints everything between START & END . I have to filter out errors too

```
awk '/START/,/END/' file
```

Comment: Im assuming you dont want to print START and END so.. `grep -v -e "START" -e "END" -e "errors" input.txt`

Comment: Not Required START & END. Requirement is to print error lines followed by heading. I have edited ques related to heading part. Just not to get confuse. 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$ awk 'f{hdg=$0; f=0} /errors|warning/{if(hdg){print hdg; hdg=""}; print} /START/{f=1}' file
Heading1
errors
Heading3
errors
```

#### How it works

- `f{hdg=$0; f=0}`

  If `f` is true (nonzero), then save the current line in the variable `hdg` and set `f` back to zero.
- `/errors|warning/{if(hdg){print hdg; hdg=""}; print}`

  If the current line contains `errors` or `warning`, then, if the variable `hdg` is non-empty, print it.  Also, print the current line.
- `/START/{f=1}`

  If the current line contains `START`, then set variable `f` to one.

#### Multiline version

For those who prefer their commands  spread over multiple lines:

```
awk '
   f {
      hdg=$0
      f=0
   }
   /errors|warning/{
      if(hdg){
         print hdg
         hdg=""
      }
      print
   }
   /START/{
      f=1
   }' file
```

#### Variation:  Add a blank line before heading

If we want a blank line to separate the output:

```
$ awk 'f{hdg=$0; f=0} /errors|warning/{if(hdg){print nl hdg; hdg=""; nl="\n"}; print} /START/{f=1}' file
Heading1
errors

Heading3
errors
```

#### Variation: Ignore errors/warnings after an END line

```
$ awk 'f{hdg=$0; f=0} g && /errors|warning/{if(hdg){print nl hdg; hdg=""; nl="\n"}; print} /START/{f=1; g=1} /END/{g=0}' file
Heading1
errors

Heading3
errors
```

To make the above case insensitive (GNU awk):

```
awk 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1} f{hdg=$0; f=0} g && /errors|warning/{if(hdg){print nl hdg; hdg=""; nl="\n"}; print} /START/{f=1; g=1} /END/{g=0}' file
```

Comment: All Good John, I was trying to check the logic here. 
Also trying to add - 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1}'  in the command to ignore error,ERROR....case sensitive

Comment: @Sin15 Very good.  And, yes, that should make the matches case-insensitive.